# Durandal: How to route away from current view within that view's activate() function?

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

I have the following:

```
function activate(routeData) {
    // make dataservice call, evaluate results here.  If condition is met, reroute:
    if (true){
       router.navigateTo("#/someRoute");
     }
    alert ("should not be shown");
}
```

The alert is getting hit however, and *then* the view changes.

How do I fully navigate away from the current item and prevent any further code in that vm from being hit?

**Update:**

I tried using `guardroute` but I have to activate the viewModel to call the dataservice that returns the data that determines whether or not I should re-route.  Using guardroute totally prevents the dataservice from getting called (since nothing in the activate function will get hit).

I also tried returning from the `if` block but this still loads the view / viewAttached / etc so the UX is glitchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's @EisenbergEffect answer to a quite similar discussion in [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/FkqXHIknT8E).

> Implement canActivate on your view model. Return a promise of false,
>   then chain with a redirect.

You might want to give @JosepfGabriel's example ([discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/LmkhbR8S5hE)) a try in Durandal 1.2. Check the correct `router` syntax for your Durandal version, you might have to substitute it with something like `router.navigateTo("#/YourHash", 'replace')`.

```
canActivate: function () {
    return system.defer(function (dfd) {
        //if step 2 has a problem
        dfd.resolve(false);
    })
    .promise()
    .then(function () { router.navigate("wizard/step1", { trigger: true, replace: true }); });
}
```

However this is NOT working in Durandal 2.0 and there's a feature request https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/203 for it.

Answer (score 14):

The following worked for me in Durandal 2.0:

```
    canActivate: function() {
        if(condition)
            return {redirect: 'otherRoute'};
        return true;
    }

    activate: // Do your stuff
```

It's mentioned in the documentation: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html

Comment: From the documentation:
As usual, you can return true/false (or a promise) from the canActivate callback. But, with the router, you can also return a route instruction that indicates a redirect url if you want to disallow activation. For example, you can return {redirect:'some/other/route'} from canActivate.

Answer (score 3):

You can't call redirect into the active method.

You can override the guardRoute method from router, to implement redirections.

You can do somehting like that:

```
router.guardRoute= function(routeInfo, params, instance){
  if(someConditios){
    return '#/someRoute'
  }
}
```

You can return a promise, true, false, the route to redirect... You can find more information about that in the next link: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Router/

Comment: What if I will only have the results of "someConditions" from within the activate method of the vm I'm trying to exit?  I'm calling an API endpoint to get data for a particular view, but if the data returned meets a condition, I need to smoothly re-route to another view.

Comment: You can check that in the guardRoute, you can know in which page you are, using the routeInfo. I know that is is not perfect, but you can`t redirect into the activate. In the next link, there are more information: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/durandaljs/redirect$20activate/durandaljs/T8luZDSvUlw/-MMw8M1RtWYJ

Comment: wait... I just tried this and I'm still running into a problem.  Within my vm's activate function I call a dataservice - my shell (where I'm putting guardroute) doesn't have access to this.  Are you saying I need to get the data from the dataservice, and somehow send it to the router?  This is confusing because in order to get the data that will determine if the route should change, I have to activate another route, so I can't be blocking/guarding it.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe, there is another way, but I don't know. :( If you explain more about what are you trying to check, I can try to help you.

Comment: Thank you - I just updated my original post - hopefully that explains what I'm facing a bit more clearly

Answer (score 1):

Rainer's answer was pretty good and works for me adding this small fix.

Inside the then() block simply call the navigation like this

```
setTimeout(function() { router.navigateTo('#/YOUR DESTINATION'); }, 200);
```

that should fix your problem. The setTimeout does the trick. Without it the newly navigated page catches the old NavigationCancel from the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a return in your if (true) block should fix this.

```
function activate(routeData) {
    if (true){
       router.navigateTo("#/someRoute");
       return;
     }
    alert ("should not be shown");
}
```

Comment: This works for 'activate' but the view that I'm navigating away from still loads, so viewAttached is hit.  I'm trying to totally exit the view

Comment: i'm a little upset I've only seen this now; maybe after 7 years you can see your error ?

Comment: Not sure I follow? What do you mean?