# Durandal.js plugin 'router'

Tags: redirect, plugins, navigation, durandal, router

How can I cancel navigation or redirecting in router, maybe smth like "router.cancelNavigation()". Or, maybe, there are some events, whitch can help me to intercept redirecting or navigation and I need to redirect router to another route...Help me please, I use Durandal and plugin "router"

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333103/durandal-how-to-route-away-from-current-view-within-that-views-activate-func

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this. Refer to the [API](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api.html#module/router/class/Router) and [documentation](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html).